# Type inference with GADTs - a0 is untouchable

Tags: haskell, gadt

Lets say I have this program

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data My a where
  A :: Int  -> My Int
  B :: Char -> My Char


main :: IO ()
main = do
  let x = undefined :: My a

  case x of
    A v -> print v

  -- print x
```

compiles fine.

But when I comment in the `print x`, I get:

```
gadt.hs: line 13, column 12:
  Couldn't match type ‘a0’ with ‘()’
    ‘a0’ is untouchable
      inside the constraints (a1 ~ GHC.Types.Int)
      bound by a pattern with constructor
                 Main.A :: GHC.Types.Int -> Main.My GHC.Types.Int,
               in a case alternative
      at /home/niklas/src/hs/gadt-binary.hs:13:5-7
  Expected type: GHC.Types.IO a0
    Actual type: GHC.Types.IO ()
  In the expression: System.IO.print v
  In a case alternative: Main.A v -> System.IO.print v
```

Why do I get this error in line 13 (`A v -> print v`) instead of only in the `print x` line?

I thought the first occurrence should determine the type.

Please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, first note that this has nothing to do with the particular `print x`: you get the same error when ending `main` with e.g. `putStrLn "done"`.

So the problem is indeed in the case block, namely in that *only the last statement of a `do` is required to have the type* of the `do` block's signature. The other statements merely have to be in the same monad, i.e. `IO a0` rather than `IO ()`.

Now, usually this `a0` is inferred from the statement itself, so for instance you can write

```
do getLine
   putStrLn "discarded input"
```

though `getLine :: IO String` rather than `IO ()`. However, in your example the information `print :: ... -> IO ()` comes from inside the `case` block, *from a GADT match*. And such GADT matches behave differently from other Haskell statements: basically, they don't let any type information escape its scope, because if the information came from the GADT constructor then it's not correct outside of the `case`.

In that particular example, it seems obvious enough that `a0 ~ ()` has nothing at all to do with the `a1 ~ Int` from the GADT match, but in general, such a fact could only be proven if GHC traced *for all type information* where it came from. I don't know if that's even possible, it would certainly be more complicated than Haskell's Hindley-Milner system, which heavily relies on *unifying* type information, which essentially assumes that it doesn't matter where the information came from.

Therefore, GADT matches simply act as a rigid “type information diode”: the stuff inside can never be used to determine types on the outside, like that the `case` block as a whole should be `IO ()`.

However, you can manually assert that, with the rather ugly

```
  (case x of
     A v -> print v
    ) :: IO ()
```

or by writing

```
  () <- case x of
          A v -> print v
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Technical nitpick: Whilst the core Haskell98 language uses a Hindley-Milner typesystem, GHC uses the more powerful System F.