# How does GHC infer the intended type for this GADT?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, type-inference, gadt

My understanding of GHC type inference was that in the absence of type annotations, it will default to Hindley-Milner. However, to my pleasant surprise GHC infers `Num p => G a -> p` for `f` as opposed to `Num p => G Char -> p`.

```
data G a where
  A :: a      -> G a
  B :: String -> G Char

f (A a) = 42
f (B s) = 24
```

My question is how does it do this and under what other situations it will infer the correct type for a GADT?

Comment: I do not really follow why you think that it should use `G Char` in the first place? Deriving types typically happens by first using the most generic type, and subsequently replacing types based on elements in the head and body of the function.

Comment: By "how does it do this" what do you mean? Do you want an explanation of Hindley-Milner in this context?

Comment: `f` does not impose any restrictions on its input, except that it should be `G`. The function does not analyze `a` or `s` any further. The fact that in `B` can be used for `G Char` only is irrelevant for deducing `f`'s type.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from not knowing that the algorithm looks for the **most generic** matching type. E.g. when looking at `f (B s)` one could be tempted to think that the argument must have type `G Char` and not the more general `G a`.

Comment: @yeputons yes, I was under the impression that Char would constrain the type variable. Thanks!

Comment: @mschmidt @yeputon answers my question, but I do know it looks for the most generic matching type. I was under the impression that `G Char` on the left hand-side in HM would constrain the type variable to be `Char` which cannot be generalised to `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GHC “disables” Hindley-Milner in GADT pattern matching, so as to prevent dynamic type information from escaping its scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582210/type-inference-with-gadts-a0-is-untouchable/28582695#28582695)

Here's a more extreme example:

```
import Data.Void

data Idiotic :: * -> * where
  Impossible :: !Void -> Idiotic Void
  Possible :: a -> Idiotic a
```

There don't exist any values of type `Void`, so it isn't possible to ever use the `Impossible` constructor. Thus, `Idiotic a` is actually isomorphic to `Identity a`, IOW to `a` itself. So, any function that takes an `Idiotic` value is fully described by just the `Possible` pattern match. Basically, it always boils down to

```
sobre :: Idiotic a -> a
sobre (Possible a) = a
```

which is easy usable in practice.

But as far as the *type system* is concerned, the other constructor matches just as well, and is in fact required to disable the `incomplete pattern` warning:

```
sobre (Impossible a) = {- Here, a::Void -} a
```

But if the compiler propagated this type information outwards, your function would end up with the completely useless signature

```
sobre :: Idiotic Void -> Void
```